# how to make argument deduction work for derived class which using base class constructor?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, c++23

When derived class using base class constructor the deduction seems always [fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894136/class-template-argument-deduction-failed-with-derived-class). However, when the base class have lots of constructors it is very clumsy to re-define all the constructors. It is also a pain when base class are quickly evolved with new constructors. The old question was asked more than 2 years ago, so I wonder: is there any work around for this in 2020 when c++17 and c++2a are available?

```
template<typename ...As>
class base_t
{
public:
    base_t(As... args){}
};

template<typename ...As>
class A_t: public base_t<As...>
{
public:
    A_t(As... args): base_t<As...>{args...} {};
};

template<typename ...As>
class B_t: public base_t<As...>
{
    using base_t<As...>::base_t;
};

int main()
{
    base_t a{1, 2.0f};
    A_t{1, 2.0f};
    B_t{1, 2.0f}; //fails unless explicitly specialize the template
    return 0;
}
```

### updates according to @Sam and @Barry:

The deduction guide is very helpful. However, for a little be more complicate situation, it still runs out of control:

```
template <typename A>
struct D_t {
    A x;
    D_t(A x) :x{x} {}
};
template<typename A, typename B>
class base2_t
{
public:
    base2_t(A a, B b){std::cout << "1\n";}
    base2_t(A a, D_t<B> c, int x){std::cout << "2\n";}
    base2_t(A a, B b, int x){std::cout << "3\n";}
    base2_t(A a, B b, int x, float y){std::cout << "4\n";}
    explicit base2_t(A(*fp)(B)){std::cout << "5\n";}
    // if we have lots of similar things like above
    // we will quickly end up write lots of different
    // guides.
};
template<typename A, typename B>
class C_t: public base2_t<A, B>
{
    using base2_t<A, B>::base2_t;
};
template<typename A, typename B, typename ...As>
C_t(A, B, As...)->C_t<A, B>;
template<typename A, typename B>
C_t(A(*)(B))->C_t<A, B>;
float func1(int x)
{
    return x;
}
int main()
{
    C_t{1, 2.0f, 3};
    base2_t{1, D_t{2.0f}, 3};
    C_t{1, D_t{2.0f}, 3}; // this is wrong, we have to deal with it by checking types and write different guides.
    base2_t{&func1};
    C_t{&func1};
}
```

till 2023, the [proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1021r6.html) is accepted in [c++23 P2582R1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2582r1.pdf) But neither [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx23) nor [llvm](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) has implemented it yet. But there is a hope that in the middle of this year this issue will finally get fixed.

Comment: Why not just define template deduction guides for the derived class `B_t`?

Comment: Deduction guides are a thing these days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being able to inherit deduction guides from base classes was [proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1021r5.html) for c++20. However, this feature didn't make it in, as the last line says:

> The wording for CTAD from inherited constructors was not finalized in time for the C++20 committee draft, and will be published in a separate wording paper at a later point in time.

So as of now, you will need to provide deduction guides for the derived class explicitly (or define the constructor as you did for `A_t`). Hopefully, this will be fixed in c++23.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's no generic way to inherit the base class' deduction guides in C++20. There was a proposal for it ([P1021](https://wg21.link/p1021)), but it didn't make it for C++20.

---

Without that proposal, it's tempting to suggest something like:

```
template <typename... Args>
Derived(Args&&... args) -> mp_rename<decltype(Base((Args&&)args...)), Derived>;
```

That is, figure out the type that you get from passing all the `args` into `Base` using class template argument deduction there - and then just rename whatever `Base<Ts...>` you get into `Derived<Ts...>`. But the grammar for a [*deduction-guide*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.guide#nt:deduction-guide) is:

> *explicit-specifier* <sub>opt</sub> *template-name* `(` *parameter-declaration-clause* `)` `->` *simple-template-id* `;`

And there's the added restriction in [[temp.deduct.guide]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.guide#3) that:

> The *template-name* shall be the same identifier as the *template-name* of the *simple-template-id*.

So a deduction guide for `Derived` has to end up with exactly `-> Derived<Args...>`. There's no way to stick any cleverness in there.

---

Without direct language help, and without the ability to do any template metaprogramming here, you're left to just carefully write the explicit deduction guides yourself. Thankfully, at least here you can write `static_assert`s to make sure you did the job right:

```
template <typename... Ts>
inline constexpr bool matches = std::is_same_v<
    decltype(Base(std::declval<Ts>()...)),
    mp_rename<decltype(Derived(std::declval<Ts>()...)), Base>>;

static_assert(matches<int>); // or whatever is reasonable for your specific types
```

Comment: thanks. But seems if things are more complicate than the example, I will end up writing lots of deduction guides for each derived class. If I have lots of them, it is still not much better than re-define the constructors.

Comment: @Wang If all you want to do is inherit, implementing a bunch of deduction guides is going to be less work than the constructors (especially since if the base class _has_ deduction guides, then you _have_ to implement deduction guides - at which point might as well do everything together).

Answer (score 2):

One option is an explicit deduction guide (C++17):

```
template<typename ...As>
class base_t
{
public:
    base_t(As... args){}
};

template<typename ...As>
class B_t: public base_t<As...>
{
    using base_t<As...>::base_t;
};

template<typename ...As>
B_t( As...) -> B_t<As...>;

int main()
{
    base_t a{1, 2.0f};
    B_t b{1, 2.0f};

    B_t<int, float> bb=b;

    return 0;
}
```

More work will probably be needed to correctly deal with references, probably by throwing in a `std::remove_reference_cv` (`remove_cvref_t` for C++20), or a `std::decay_t` somewhere in there...

Answer (score 2):

You could use @Barry's rename Idea with a layer of indirection:

```cpp
template<class... Args>
struct ctad_tag{};

template<class... Args>
struct deriv : base<Args...> {
    using base<Args...>::base;
};

template<class... Args>
struct deriv<ctad_tag<Args...>> : deriv<Args...> {
    using deriv<Args...>::deriv;
};

template<class... Args>
deriv(Args&&... args) 
-> deriv<rename_t<decltype(base(std::forward<Args>(args)...)), ctad_tag>>;
```

But it's a little hacky, since you'll end up with a `deriv<ctad_tag<...>>` instead of a `deriv<...>`. Still, depending on the use case this might be fine, so I'll leave this here.

Working example: https://godbolt.org/z/ygWpJU