# Inherit CTAD constructor

Tags: c++, c++17, stdtuple, ctad

I have derived from `std::tuple` and but was unable construct the derived class from an initializer list due to issues with class template argument deduction. Is there a better way to construct such a class beyond just giving it an already constructed tuple `first{ std::tuple{1, 1.0f, 1u} };`.

```
template <typename T, typename... Types>
struct first : public std::tuple<T, Types...>
{
    //using std::tuple<T, Types...>::tuple;
    template<typename F>
        requires std::invocable<F, T>
    auto transform(F f)
    {
        auto result = *this;
        std::get<0>(result) = f(std::get<0>(result));
        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    //auto tuple = first{ 1, 1.0f, 1u };
    auto tuple = first{ std::tuple{1, 1.0f, 1u} };
    auto tuple2 = tuple.transform([](auto a) {return a + 3; });
}
```

Comment: Related to [class-template-argument-deduction-failed-with-derived-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46894136/class-template-argument-deduction-failed-with-derived-class) and [how-to-make-argument-deduction-work-for-derived-class-which-using-base-class-constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61311297/how-to-make-argument-deduction-work-for-derived-class-which-using-base-class-con)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inherited constructors are not part of CTAD.

You might replicate [std::tuple's CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/deduction_guides):

```
template <typename T, typename... Types>
first(T, Types...) -> first<T, Types...>;

// auto tuple = first{1, 1.0f, 1u}; // is ok now
// auto tuple = first{ std::tuple{1, 1.0f, 1u} }; // broken now
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yn844G4h8)

Answer (score 2):

I can't exactly tell you why the `using std::tuple<T, Types...>::tuple;` directive doesn't work here, but everything seems to work fine, if you simply define the constructors for taking the parameters `T, Types...` and for taking a `std::tuple<T, Types...>` manually:

```
template <typename T, typename... Types>
struct first : public std::tuple<T, Types...>
{
    first(T&& t, Types&&... vals)
        : std::tuple<T, Types...>{t, std::forward<Types>(vals)...}
    {}

    first(std::tuple<T, Types...>&& t)
        : std::tuple<T, Types...>(t)
    {}

    template<typename F>
        requires std::invocable<F, T>
    auto transform(F f)
    {
        auto result = *this;
        std::get<0>(result) = f(std::get<0>(result));
        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto tuple1 = first{1, 1.0f, 1u};
    auto tuple2 = first{std::tuple{1, 1.0f, 1u}};
    auto tuple3 = tuple2.transform([](auto a) {return a + 3; });

    std::cout << std::get<0>(tuple1) << ", " << std::get<1>(tuple1) << ", " << std::get<2>(tuple1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<0>(tuple3) << ", " << std::get<1>(tuple3) << ", " << std::get<2>(tuple3) << std::endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
1, 1, 1
4, 1, 1
```

This is what you intended?

Comment: With `first(T&& t, Types&&... vals)`, you only expect rvalue reference (unless types are specified for lvalue reference). `int i =42; first{i};` won't compile.

Comment: *"I can't exactly tell you why [..]"* See linked question, CTAD is not inherited.